# Jquery different data trapped from direct mousedown event and simulation via $(this).trigger('mousedown');

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, mouseevent

I need to trap some data in my webpage then user make a mousedown event or simulate it when user press TAB key on a page element.
For mousedown i use standard code like:

```
$('*').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    // make sure the event isn't bubbling
    if (e.target != this) {
        return;
    }
    //...my code
 });
```

and all work done, for TAB key pressure i use this code for simulate mousedown event

```
$(':input').keydown(function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

  if (keyCode == 9) {
    $(this).trigger('mousedown');
  }
});
```

and all seems to be done, but then i look at the e data with

```
console.dir(e)
```

there are many difference and in second case many missed data:

SAME ELEMENT CLICK AND TAB EVENTS

CLICK
mousedown event:

[image]

TAB
and with $(this).trigger('mousedown');

[image]

There are far fewer data!! For example i need e.pageX and e.pageY parameters but if i trigger event there aren't.
How can i have the same e data on both case??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like an xy problem, why would you need to simulate mousedown event?FYI, this is the worst selector you can get `$('*')`, bind event to `document` instead and use `event.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first print, you could see the "OriginalEvent: MouseEvent" which is the one that provides the pageX/pageY...when you simulate "mousedown" you don't have the original event.  Depending on which event type triggered the handler you can't access the original event. Maybe this is the case.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. The event is the same, mousedown, and both on the same element (but i don't understand why currentTarget data are different)

Comment: Hi...I've simulated your situation here: 
mousedown from mouse: currentTarget is the input which you're clicking (focus on)
mousedown from tab: currentTarget is the NEXT input which assumes focus AND, if you look console, you'll see that previous currentTarget (from mousedown's mouse) change to the same currentTarget of the TAB click. What do you want to do with this?